# accordion-toggle on table row but prevent on specific cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

Using accordion-toggle on a table to show extra info when people click a certain row. But this row has some links that perform some other actions and I wanted that when they were clicked the extra row didn't appear.

Here's the markup:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#info16" class="accordion-toggle">
    <td class="notice-green"></td>
    <td class="notice-green"></td>
    <td>16 <a href="x.php?id=16">XXXX</a></td>
    <td>2014-10-27 01:57:00</td>
    <td>2014-10-27 21:45:00</td>
    <td>2014-10-27 21:45:00</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="sync"><b class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></b></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" class="rowHide">
    <div class="accordian-body" id="info16">Extra info</p></div>
</td>
```

Is it possible to get the table row NOT expanding when either of the links is clicked? Already tried to mess around with the .collapse() methods and opts with no success so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the link click bubbles to your row as well, try

```
$("td a").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

you can most likely fine tune your selector even better

Comment: The table row keeps expanding when the link is clicked with "td a" selector... 
I added .linkrt and .sync classes to both links respectively, targeted those and still expands also...

Comment: Nevermind, worked for the first link, but on the second link I have some other jQuery code running and manage to fix it also! Thanks. Accepted and upvoted.